# How can you interact with a copied+pasted Table using Microsoft Office Word Interop? Pasted table doesn't add to document.Tables.count

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, office-interop

I'm copying and pasting a table using the following code:

```
Word.Table tableTemplate = document.Tables[tableNumber];
tableTemplate.Select();
word.Selection.Copy();    //word is my Word.Application
word.Selection.MoveDown(Word.WdUnits.wdLine, 2);
word.Selection.PasteAndFormat(Word.WdRecoveryType.wdTableOriginalFormatting);
table = document.Tables[tableNumber + 1];
```

Unfortunately, the document.Tables.Count variable isn't incremented when the table is pasted, and the last line throws an index out of bounds error. I'm sure it's something minor I'm missing.

Comment: I know nothing about Word Interop, but if you just do the copy and paste, but not the last access (that throws the error), and open the resultant document up in word, does the newly pasted table actually exist?

Comment: Good point that the frustrated mind often misses. It turns out that the pasted table is being appended to the original table. Perhaps I need to insert a paragraph between. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Yeah. Sometimes it's really easy to miss the obvious - especially when you really know how it supposed to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone having a similar problem is looking for a solution, I placed a bookmark below the table, moved the selection cursor there, then selected the range just before the bookmark and pasted.

```
Word.Bookmark bkmrk = document.Bookmarks["MyBkmrk"];
Word.Range rng = document.Range(bkmrk.Range.Start - 1, bkmrk.Range.Start - 1);
rng.Select();
word.Selection.Paste();
```

This seemed to work infinitely better than trying to use MoveDown. I'd even tried using MoveDown in the selection by using the number of paragraphs in the range to determine how far, and that entirely didn't work.

Edit:

So, my real issue was that I needed to copy a table and paste some number of them in a loop, then edit the contents of the table. I kept running into the table pasting into itself and just generally being messed up. For anyone who needs to do something similar, here's some help:

```
Word.Table table = document.Tables[tableNumber];
table.Select();
wordApplication.Selection.Copy();
for(int i = 0; i < tablesINeed; i++)
{
    Word.Range rng = document.Range(document.Tables[tableNumber + i].Range.End + 1, document.Tables[tableNumber + i].Range.End + 1);
    rng.Select();
    wordApplication.Selection.Paste();
    // Modify table accordingly
}
```

It looks simple, but it took a lot of trial and error. Hopefully it will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

I have an answer based on cboler's. I had problems if there is already something behind the table to be copied.

```
private static List<Table> CloneTables(Application Application, Document doc, int tableNumber, int tablesINeed)
    {
        List<Table> sameTables = new List<Table>();
        Table lastTable = doc.Tables[tableNumber];
        sameTables.Add(lastTable);

        lastTable.Select();
        Application.Selection.Copy();
        for (int i = 0; i < tablesINeed; i++)
        {
            lastTable.Range.Next().InsertParagraphAfter();
            Range rng = doc.Range(doc.Tables[tableNumber + i].Range.End + 1, doc.Tables[tableNumber + i].Range.End + 1);
            rng.Select();
            Application.Selection.Paste();
            lastTable = doc.Tables[tableNumber + i + 1];
            sameTables.Add(lastTable);
        }

        return sameTables;
    }
```